# Is there a way for a Content Editor Web Part to query like a Query Web Part?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007

I have a Content Editor Web Part where I am using scrolling Javascript to display text.  I need to query my news section with all its articles while maintaining the scrolling.  I know I can hard code the links, but I would like to not have to enter a new link every time a manager adds news.  Is it possible to do this?  Or on the other end, is it possible to edit the Content Query Web Part to scroll vertically?

Thanks.

My Javascript is:

```
<style type="text/css">

#marqueecontainer{
position: relative;
width: 200px; /*marquee width */
height: 200px; /*marquee height */
background-color: white;
overflow: hidden;
border: 3px solid white;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Cross browser Marquee II- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more.
***********************************************/

var delayb4scroll=2000 //Specify initial delay before marquee starts to scroll on page (2000=2 seconds)
var marqueespeed=1 //Specify marquee scroll speed (larger is faster 1-10)
var pauseit=1 //Pause marquee onMousever (0=no. 1=yes)?

////NO NEED TO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE////////////

var copyspeed=marqueespeed
var pausespeed=(pauseit==0)? copyspeed: 0
var actualheight=''

function scrollmarquee(){
if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)>(actualheight*(-1)+8)) //if scroller hasn't reached the end of its height
cross_marquee.style.top=parseInt(cross_marquee.style.top)-copyspeed+"px" //move scroller upwards
else //else, reset to original position
cross_marquee.style.top=parseInt(marqueeheight)+8+"px"
}

function initializemarquee(){
cross_marquee=document.getElementById("vmarquee")
cross_marquee.style.top=0
marqueeheight=document.getElementById("marqueecontainer").offsetHeight
actualheight=cross_marquee.offsetHeight //height of marquee content (much of which is hidden from view)
if (window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Netscape/7")!=-1){ //if Opera or Netscape 7x, add scrollbars to scroll and exit
cross_marquee.style.height=marqueeheight+"px"
cross_marquee.style.overflow="scroll"
return
}
setTimeout('lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",30)', delayb4scroll)
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initializemarquee, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initializemarquee)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=initializemarquee


</script>


<div id="marqueecontainer" onMouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onMouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">
<div id="vmarquee" style="position: absolute; width: 98%;">

<!--YOUR SCROLL CONTENT HERE-->

<h4>Your scroller contents</h4>

<!--YOUR SCROLL CONTENT HERE-->

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the Content By Query Web Part can be modified by editing some XSLT, so you should be able to add the required div's and classes to make it autoscroll with your javascript function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557.aspx